# how to make a glowing effect to a star image

Tags: html

I have a star image.i want to change it's effect to glowing on onclick.I tried to change it color by using the code

onclick= "document.bgcolor="red"" inside the image src tag.But it dosen't work for me.Can anyone help guide me to some good tutorial or some sample codes

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to create another image that has the desired effect, ie the glow.
Add `id="star"` to your `<img>` tag then use javascript to swap the non-glowing image with the glowing image when it is clicked.

```
var image1 = document.getElementById('star');
var image2 = "http://link/to/new/image.png";

function changeImage() {
  image1.setAttribute('src', image2);
}


image1.addEventListener("click", changeImage, false);
```

NOTE - change the value of `image2` to match the path to the new image